# tvOS XC UI Test swipe remote gestures

Tags: xcode7, tvos, xctest

Does anyone know how to handle swipe gestures for a UI XCTest on tvOS? I have a hidden nav bar at the top of my page which will appear when swiping down on the remote. I can't seem to replicate this using `XCUIRemote.shared.press(.down)` in the UI Test. Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the API (https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuiremote) it seems currently not possible.